# What does the colon mean in Javascript after function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I saw the Facebook F8 app code there is a ":" after the function

```
function setup(): React.Component {
  ...
}
```

What does this mean?

Inheritance?

Comment: Looks like a return type annotation in TypeScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it's flowtype annotation and in this case means that `setup()` returns a React.Component. Or it could be TypeScript as well, can't make sophisticated guess in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

I think that is the return type of the function setup(), if you analyze different examples you will see that syntax in method parameters too

```
function user(state: State = initialState, action: Action): State {
  // some code
  return state;
}
```

edit: is flow, a static type checker from facebook: https://flow.org/