# What is the purpose of `(function(): Something{})` syntax?

Tags: typescript

`(function() : Contract {`…`})`.

I was expecting IIFE but this colon?
It’s not a label?

[image]

Comment: That's TypeScript, not JavaScript. It's specifying the return type of the function.

Comment: Look at the rest of the code. After every variable there's a type declaration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different types of function declaration (foo () : void{} vs foo() {}) Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654776/different-types-of-function-declaration-foo-void-vs-foo-angular2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does the colon mean in Javascript after function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740493/what-does-the-colon-mean-in-javascript-after-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is TypeScript syntax, not JavaScript. The colon indicates that the function will return something which is of type Contract.

For example, with

```
const foo = (function(): Foo {
  // lots of code
  return someExpression;
})();
```

this would indicate - and have TypeScript require - that the `someExpression` is of type Foo.

In TypeScript, noting the return type of functions like this is usually optional. Most of the time, you can omit it entirely and let TS infer it automatically if you wish. (which is what I prefer to cut down on syntax noise)

Comment: Although it's kind of weird for an IIFE to return anything if the result isn't assigned.

Comment: :facepalm. Definitely too late for me. Going to bed now.